# The image cannot be displayed after posting a new form data

Tags: reactjs, mongodb

**Profile.jsx**

```
const Profile = () => {
    const [auth, setAuth] = useAuth()
    const [name, setName] = useState("")
    const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
    const [password, setPassword] = useState("");
    const [phone, setPhone] = useState("");
    const [address, setAddress] = useState("");
    const [photo, setPhoto] = useState("")
    const navigate = useNavigate()

    console.log(photo.path)

    useEffect(() => {
        const { name, email, phone, address, photo } = auth?.user
        setName(name);
        setPhone(phone);
        setEmail(email);
        setAddress(address);
        setPhoto(photo)
    }, [auth?.user])

    const handleSubmit = async(e) => {
        e.preventDefault()

        const data = new FormData()
        data.append("name", name)
        data.append("email", email)
        data.append("password", password)
        data.append("phone", phone)
        data.append("address", address)
        if(photo){
            data.append("photo", photo)
        }
  
        try{
            const res = await axios.put("http://localhost:4000/api/auth/profile", data)
            if(res.data.success) {
                toast(res.data.message,{type: "success", draggable:false})
                navigate("/")
            } else {
                toast(res.data.message,{type: "error", draggable:false})
            }
        } catch(error){
            console.log(error);
            toast("Something Went Wrong",{type: "error", draggable:false})
        }
    }
    return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
          <div className='input-photo'>
                                        {photo && (
                                            <div>
                                                {/* <img src={photo.path} alt='Profile photo' /> */}
                                                <img src={URL.createObjectURL(photo)} alt='Profile photo' />
                                            </div>
                                        )}
                                        <div className="">
                                            <label>
                                                {photo ? photo.name : "Upload Photo"}
                                                <input type='file' name='photo' accept='image/*'
                                                onChange={(e) => setPhoto(e.target.files[0])} hidden />
                                            </label>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
    </form>
    )
)
```

**controllers/auth.js**

```
export const updateProfileController = async(req,res) => {
    try{
        const { name, email, password, address, phone } = req.body
        const photo = req.files[0]
        const user = await userModel.findById(req.user._id)

        if(password && password.length < 6){
            return res.json({ error: "Password required and 6 characters long"})
        }

        const hashedPassword = password ? await hashPassword(password) : undefined

        console.log(photo)
        const updatedUser = await userModel.findByIdAndUpdate(req.user._id, 
            {
                name: name || user.name,
                email: email || user.email,
                password: hashedPassword || user.password,
                phone: phone || user.phone,
                address: address || user.address,
                photo: photo || user.photo
            },
            { new: true }
        )
    

        res.status(200).send({
            success: true,
            message: "Profile updated successfully",
            updatedUser,
        });
    } catch(error){
        console.log(error);
        res.status(400).send({
            success: false,
            message: "Error while updating profile",
            error,
        });
    }
}
```

**models/user.js**

```
 photo: {
            type: {},
        },
```

I am trying to display the photo that has been saved in MongoDB and since because I used `URL.createObjectURL` to display so the user can change the profile photo. May I ask how to have the photo first displayed the original ones then when the user clicks on the input field then the photo can be shown as well?